# Unsupported get request - Facebook Marketing API won't authenticate for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm setting up an API integration in my rails application with the Facebook Ads/Marketing API. I'm attempting to test very basic options with my Sandbox Ad Account and cannot seem to get them to work. This is error I keep getting:

```
FacebookAds::ClientError: Unsupported post request. 
Object with ID '119033245616727' does not exist, cannot be loaded due 
to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
Please read the Graph API documentation at 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api: (fbtrace_id: GyiFjx24NY/)
from /Users/kelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/facebookads-0.2.11.0/lib/facebook_ads/api_request.rb:67:in `create_response'
```

To run the test, I used their **Marketing API** quickstart to get my access token, app secret and ad account id.

**This is my rails config:**

Gemfile:

```
gem 'facebookads' #https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-ads-sdk
```

My Test Module:

```
module Advertising
  module Facebook
    class API
      attr_accessor :access_token
      attr_accessor :app_secret
      attr_accessor :ad_account_id

      def initialize
        @access_token = 'EAAYVZBezhACwBAKwMk7fhAJO2WFlUeUaCcASveD9gb6ZCKBzEAJIzDToagt4Vy5n6Ue9QpOwyb0SWYCSHHf4A2jbdTOb99GTBjhSOu5WnU03mnKymd2YgmquOJHg4lPx3iZBonYTzriU27OnlBXDMXdIZApwt45SSqQ8SLs5xaMM3lVEsm0r6WXSoos5yiOiqfMB83SfnntzUzqkEywQ'
        @app_secret = '15326d2073b04504ef72267bf36a8bd4'
        @ad_account_id = '119033245616727'
      end

      def test1
        FacebookAds.configure do |config|
         config.access_token = @access_token
         config.app_secret = @app_secret
        end
        ad_account = FacebookAds::AdAccount.get(ad_account_id)
        ad_account.campaigns.create(
          objective: 'LINK_CLICKS',
          status: 'PAUSED',
          buying_type: 'AUCTION',
          name: 'My Campaign'
        )
      end

      def test2
        # With session
        session = FacebookAds::Session.new(access_token: @access_token, app_secret: @app_secret)
        ad_account = FacebookAds::AdAccount.get(ad_account_id, session)
        puts "This is my account name: #{ad_account.name}"
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Then I'm running this in the rails console:

```
ad = Advertising::Facebook::API.new()
ad.test1
# OR
ad.test2
```

This is a newly created facebook app. These are the settings:

**Status:** In Development

**App ID:** 1713013025472556

**App Secret:** 15326d2073b04504ef72267bf36a8bd4

I added the Marketing API to the products section and created a Sandbox Ad Account called T2 Sandbox (119033245616727).

Answer (score 1):

When setting your ad_account_id, add 'act_' in front of the ID. As the SDK will not do this for you.